# Npgsql PostgreSQL Data Provider missing from Entity Framework 6 Data Sources

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-6, npgsql

All,

I'm evaluating PostgreSQL and Npgsql as a replacement for SQL Server for an application developed by our organization. I've created a sample C# Console Application, but I'm unable to add an entity data model to the project for PostgreSQL because the .NET Data Provider is not displayed on the Data Sources dialog.

[image]

I've installed the Npgsql PostgreSQL Integration (v3.2.7) extension. I had also installed the latest packages for Npgsql (v4.0.2) and EntityFramework6.Npgsql (v3.2.0). I observed that [this page](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ddex.html) indicates that version mismatches could cause issues, so I reverted to v3.2.7 & 3.1.1 respectively. Still no luck. Strange thing is that I do see it when attempting to establish a connection via Server Explorer.

[image]

Anyone have any ideas why I might not be able to see the data source when attempting to generate the entity data model? Do the selected versions not include support for VS2017? Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem with VS 2019 and posted a solution here: [PostgreSQL does not appear in Data Source when generating .ADO.net Entity Data Model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56103235/774575)